# Django Rest Framework: How to send data to request.data

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework, request

Im building a simple api in Django Rest Framework using class based views and the documentation mentions request.data (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/)

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
    class myView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
```

When I try to send post requests either with

1. curl: `curl --data param1=val1&param2=val2 url`
2. djangos browser interface with post (using formatted url and the post option
3. Advanced Rest Client (chrome add on)

The data of all three appears to end up in request.query_params.
When I try to print request.data, however I get an empty response `{}`

I could just use request.query_params, Im just curious as to how one would get data to go to request.data since it is talked about in the documentation

edit: so `curl --data param1=val1&param2=val2 -X POST url` sends information to request.data  (now if I say request.query_params if get the empty dict {} but request.data contains an object that is the dict query_params.)

Comment: Visit this https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58. It may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**curl** request doesn't have the **-X** and **POST** added.
Add these